# onOpen function fails to run when Google Sheets file is opened

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

I've a problem with `onOpen()` function in Google Script.

It works perfect for setting extra menu in ui:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Menu')
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Incoming')
          .addItem('Add line', 'addLine')
          .addItem('Add multiple lines', 'addMultipleLines')
          .addSeparator()
          .addItem('Add service', 'addService'))
      .addToUi();
  validateData();
}
```

UI is loading normally, however `validateData()` won't run.

On top of it if I'll go to Google Script and run `onOpen()` function manually then `validateData()` works normally.

Do you have an idea why it won't run when the spreadsheet is opened?

Comment: Review the restrictions on simple triggers in apps script documentation. Since you don't share what your validation code does, we can't help your further then saying "you probably do stuff there that a simple trigger cannot do."

Comment: Did you tried putting validateDate() as first statement in the fucntion, try enclosing it within try and catch block and log if any exceptions happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As tehhowch said, it's more than likely a restriction caused by some part of your `validateData()` function.

Creating an installed `onOpen()` trigger would make it work the way you expect.

[image]

Comment: Your solution works! Thank you very much.

After doing the try catch I found that there was a problem with URL fetch. Once I added that trigger works like a charm.